# How to upgrade to Python 3.7 with existing module named `async`?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.7

Hi I have a big Python project that has a package named `async` that breaks after migrating to Python3.7

```
import foo.bar.async.x.y as y
               ^^^^^ syntax error :(
```

What's a suggested way to fix/workaround this issue?

The most straightforward I can think of is to rename it and refactor all its references. But is there any more scoped solution than the massive refactoring?

Comment: `async` is now a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords), so you can't use it as an identifier.  You'll need to change that name wherever it appears.

Answer (score 2):

Renaming the module to avoid the keyword clash is the only way forward.

Many open source libraries had to do the same, and [even some stdlib libraries](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#async-await-in-cpython-code-base).

Comment: This is such a horrible break of backward compatibility :(

Comment: Rather than renaming - I created a symlink to the existing `async` package file with a new name.

You can import using the new name for Python >= 3.7 while any older code can continue to uses the package the same way it always has.